# GWT module is missing

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I got several GWT facets in my projects. They are getting detected and I can see them in "Project Structure"/"Project Settings"/"Facets" menu. However when I try to setup "Run/Debug Configuration" for GWT, I cannot see any GWT module in drop-down list for my project. The drop-down list is enabled, but the only value I see there is "All". Tried almost everything I could think of, but no luck.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Any help is appreciated.

P.S. Intellij IDEA 11.0.2.

Comment: Do you have a `module.gwt.xml` file for the module you are trying to run?  If so, it may be in the wrong location of your file structure.

Answer (score 5):

Please check that you have GWT modules (*.gwt.xml files) under source roots of IDEA modules chosen in 'Module' combobox of the run configuration. Source roots of a module are shown in the Project Structure dialog (File | Project Structure | Modules |  node | 'Sources' tab).